# aID in js function toggleAndChange(aID,divID) not defined in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following javascript function in the `<head>` to toggle visibility of a `<div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleAndChange(aID,divID) {
    $(divID).toggle();
    if ($(divID).css('display') == 'none') {
        $(aID).html('Show Description');
    } else {
        $(aID).html('Hide Description');
    }   
}
</script>
```

In the `<body>` I have the following code

```
<a id="description_visibility" href="javascript:toggleAndChange(description_visibility,description);">Hide Description</a><br />
<div id="description">....</div>
```

This works fine in IE and Chrome. In FF when I click on the link nothing happens. When I have up Firebug and click on the link it says:

```
description_visibility is not defined
```

Why does FF not recognize the `<a>` id? Or am I missing something? Issue on both FF 9.0.1 on my Mac and FF 8.0.1 on my PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a single quotes for '#description_visibility' and '#description'

```
<a id="description_visibility" href="javascript:toggleAndChange('#description_visibility','#description')"></a>
```

And also numeral signs to specify that those are IDS

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. I tried to use just the single quotes, but it was the numeral sign '#' that made it work. Not sure why this works without the '#' on one of my other servers, but not this one. I just copied the script, but then found that it did not work. Thanks for you help, and quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on a non-standard feature in some browsers where they put all element IDs as properties on the global object mapping to those elements.  Firefox only does this in quirks mode, not in standards mode.